Force Python auto-imports from current package to be prefixed with this package's name
I use Python and Pylance extensions in VSCode.
In my own package that I'm editing, the automatically added imports (with setting "Import Format: absolute") look like this:
from mydirectory.myfile import myclass

However, my Python package is being consumed by a (very dumb and non-negotiable) external system that refuses to interpret it correctly unless imports are formatted specifically like:
from mypackage.mydirectory.myfile import myclass

So how can I force VSCode to auto-complete those imports in that exact format?
I tried many VSC settings related to imports, formatting, Python, Pylance, etc. already, but so far none of them did what I need. I suspect maybe some manually forced prefixes are needed? (I have only one package, so it would be fine to hardcode a prefix like that with a specific string.)

dumb hack warning: recursive symlink? I.e. symlink in mydirectory named mypackage that points to mydirectory? not sure if this would work, and it probably wouldn't remove import options for not going through the symlink, and you'd also probably get recursive import options... also, I wonder if python.analysis.extraPaths supports ../.

I think I'll pass setting up recursive symlinks in my filesystem when I'm not even familiar enough with the normal ones - thanks for the idea though :D

As for python.analysis.extraPaths supporting ../, no, it doesn't seem to. When I have only that set up in my extraPaths (instead of the actual path to the package), the imports don't get suggested at all.

You could try to add the following settings to your settings.json` and specify the import strategy:
  "python.analysis.importFormat": "absolute",
  "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["path/to/your/package"] 


I already had all of those settings besides "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true, but switching it on didn't change anything. The format is still the same.

Hello, you tried to write it as an absolute path. And then import it as you described, would that be useful?
